# Escape quotes in captured group inside a shell scipt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this line in my shell script:

```
MYSQL_GENPASS=($echo -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=`openssl rand -base64 37 | sed -e 's/^\(.\{37\}\).*/\1/g'`)
```

Later on I call the output of this line with:

```
echo -e "\nYour MySQL password ENV variable is: " $MYSQL_GENPASS
```

`$MYSQL_GENPASS` output also will be called on a docker-compose script.

How I can escape `"`, `'` and ` characters in the captured format?

Comment: See the POSIX spec for `echo` -- if you read it closely, you'll see that any implementation that does anything when given `echo -e` other than print `-e` on its output is noncompliant. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html

Comment: Also, using `echo -e` [on a shell that breaks the standard by implementing it to honor backslash-escape sequences] means that such sequences inside your password will be interpreted by `echo` itself. If you used `printf`, and passed the variable out-of-band from the format string, you wouldn't have that issue.

Comment: ...which is to say: `printf '\nYour mysql password ENV variable can be set by the code: %s\n' "$MYSQL_GENPASS"` -- unlike `echo -e`, that *only* honors escape sequences inside the format string itself.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I'd call this "GENPASS" -- I mean, it's generating just one password up-front when it's called, not a new one each time; if you wanted the latter, you'd want to write a function.

Comment: (well -- I *definitely* wouldn't call it GENPASS all-caps, as that's out of compliance with POSIX-defined convention; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph -- search for "reserved for applications" -- keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you're trying to do here is generate a string which can be evaluated as a shell command. `printf %q` is an extension in ksh -- adopted by bash and others -- which does any and all escaping necessary to make a string `eval`-safe:

```
printf -v mysql_genpass 'MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=%q' "$(openssl rand -base64 37 | head -c 37)"
```

...will put a command into `$mysql_genpass` which, when executed with `eval "$mysql_genpass"` or an equivalent, will set `MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

(`printf -v var ...` assigns results of evaluating a format string to a variable more efficiently than `var=$(printf ...)` does, as the latter requires forking a subshell).

---

That said, unless you have a compelling reason to do so, assigning shell fragments to scalar variables is best avoided. See [BashFAQ #50 ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but complex cases always fail!")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and [BashFAQ #48 ("Eval command and security issues")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048); generally speaking, it's preferable to pass data around as literal data rather than generating code.